# Why Next.JS page with fllaback returning 404

Tags: next.js

It is my first project in next JS. I have site based on blog posts, categories etc.
Blog can have a lot of psts and categories so I dont want to prerender all posts at the build time so i am using fallback: true in getStaticPaths

[image]

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    return {
        paths: [],
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const postId = params?.slug || ''

    const post: any = await fetchPost({
        slug: Array.isArray(postId) ? postId[0] : postId,
        include: ['authors', 'category', 'seo']
    })

    const relatedPosts: any = await fetchPostsByCategory({
        limit: 3,
        category: post.data.category.slug,
        pageOffset: 0,
        include: ['authors']
    })

    return {
        props: {
            post,
            posts: relatedPosts.data || null,
            passwordRequired: post.data!.encrypted_page
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine on my local environment but on production I am getting 404 Not Found on each page generated in this way.

Im am using following script to build app

```
next build && next export
```